# Is it possible for a node to have two parents in a vega tree?

Tags: d3.js, tree, parent-child, vega

I'm attempting to create a Greek Gods family tree for a vega assignment and I am using vega's tree layout, however, I am unable to have a node with two parents. In addition to this problem, I cannot see a way to have two starting nodes (Kronos and Rhea). Is there any way to have a node stemming from two other nodes?

Edit: I see that there is something called a "tangled tree" in D3 that allows a node to have two parents. Is there something similar to that in Vega?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible unless you grouped the couples. I found this picture online that may help. Alternatively you could attempt to plot the generations with a [parallel coordinates graph](https://vega.github.io/vega/examples/parallel-coordinates/) - but I'm not sure whether generations are really a thing with immortals...

[image]